# How to compile Elm with React in Browserify

Tags: reactjs, browserify, elm

I want to start using Elm in a React project, but they are not using Webpack, they are using Browserify with Gulp instead. How can I get Elm to be compiled with Browserify?

Comment: Have you tried [gulp-elm](https://github.com/gulp-elm/gulp-elm#readme)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, the best way around it I found was to compile the Elm code first, and only then compile the JS. This means that, unlike when using `elm-webpack-loader` where you can require the `.elm` files directly form JS, I have to require the compiled elm code.

Here is a Gulp task to compile all `Main.elm` files in a directory or any of its subdirectories into a single `.js` file. You can then require the modules with

```
import { Widget1, Widget2 } from "../compilation-folder/myapp.js"
```

Here is the task:

```
const path = require("path");
// const execSync = require("child_process").execSync;
const shell = require("gulp-shell");
const glob = require("glob");

// Compiles all Main.elm files in a specified src folder and its subfolders
// into the output file specified
module.exports = (src, dest, outname) => {
    const output = path.join(dest, `${outname}`);

    return done => {
        glob(src + "/**/Main.elm", {}, (err, filesArray) => {
            const files = filesArray.join(" ");
            shell.task(`elm-make --yes ${files} --output=${output}`)(done)
        })
    }
};
```

You can use it like this:

```
const buildElm = require("./fileWithCodeAbove.js")

gulp.task("build-elm", buildElm("./elm-directory", "./build-directory", "myapp.js");
```